# Why does django paginator.num_pages returns one even when no objects are in db?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a paginator for my model but I want the pagination to appear only when there are models saved in my db.

I tried in my template

```
{% if page.paginator.num_pages != 0 %}
    #show pagination ul
{%endif%}
```

but didn't work. Apparently paginator object when created always has one page even if there aren't any objects in the objlist. I had to go around this using the object_list.count() method

```
{% if page.object_list.count != 0 %}
    #show pagination ul
{% endif %}
```

I don't have enough data to test it yet but is this the right way? Is there another one maybe better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the paginator is instantiated with `allow_empty_page=True`, then it will have one page even if there are no objects. See the [paginator docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/#paginator-objects) for more info.

If you want to show the paginator when there is at least one object in the object list, then use:

```
{% if page.object_list.count %}
    #show pagination ul
{% endif %}
```

If you only want the paginator to appear when there is more than one page, then use:

```
{% if page.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
    #show pagination ul
{%endif%}
```

Comment: Yes this is how i do it as you can see in my post using count. But was checking with zero value cause i didn't see the allow_empty_page in the docs :) Thank you!

Comment: +1 `{% if page.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}` exactly what I needed to decide about displaying or not pagination navgigation.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate Paginator with `allow_empty_first_page=False` (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/)) This optional argument is `True` by default.

If `allow_empty_first_page` is `True` then an empty page is still a page. This means `num_pages` is one even though there are no objects. If `allow_empty_first_page` is `False` then `num_pages` can be zero.

You can then iterate through `page.paginator.page_range` as normal:

```
{% for page_number in page.paginator.page_range %}
    # show link to page
{% endfor %}
```

This won't show any pagination links as `page_range` will end up being an empty list.

Comment: I ended up using the count method since i wanted to create a "dynamic" paginator. I dont want to show all pages but was trying to show only some (example the first 5) then dots(...) then the last. So paginator.page_range didn't do it for since it iterates over every page.